# How to remove the first column from all files and replace?

Tags: unix, sed, cut, csv

I have several tab-delimited files, e.g. the file looks like this:

```
A213<TAB>foo bar<TAB>sentence
A123<TAB>bar foo<TAB>sentence
B84521<TAB>abc hello<TAB>world
C984<TAB>def word<TAB>hello
```

I need it to remove the first column and the substitute the tabs with `|||`, the output should look as such:

```
foo bar ||| sentence
bar foo ||| sentence
abc hello ||| world
def word ||| hello
```

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$ cut -f2,3 file.txt | sed 's/<TAB>/\s|||\s/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=" ||| "} {print $2, $3}' file
foo bar ||| sentence
bar foo ||| sentence
abc hello ||| world
def word ||| hello
```

It is just a matter of defining the input and output field separators accordingly. Then, print second and third fields.

With `cut` + `sed` you could use:

```
$ cut -d$'\t' -f2- < file | sed 's/\t/|||/' 
foo bar|||sentence
bar foo|||sentence
abc hello|||world
def word|||hello
```

In all cases note you have to indicate what is the field separator.